# Javascript gets 'GET https://www.purpleair.com/json 400 (Bad Request)' on JSON request

Tags: javascript, json

I have a basic Javascript web application that sends a JSON request and reads the data returned from the request. One week ago this code was functioning fine with no errors. When I checked it today, it fails every time. I have not edited anything in the meantime. This is the JSON request part of my code.

```
function Get(yourUrl){
  var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
  Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
  Httpreq.send(null);
  return Httpreq.responseText;
}

var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get('https://www.purpleair.com/json'));
results = json_obj.results;
```

The full readout on the console is:

```
    [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

    GET https://www.purpleair.com/json 400 (Bad Request)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the deal is? The website that I send the JSON request to doesn't appear to have changed since I last ran this, I'm just totally confused.

Comment: The 400 request has an error message attached: `An empty querystring is not permitted. Please contact PurpleAir at contact@purpleair.com for assistance.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in developer tools - something have changed obviously:

[image]

The warning about deprecated sync request is just warning - but we can fix it with async request...
The bad request ...seems to be fixed with anything added to querystring...

```js
function Get(yourUrl, yourHandler){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,true); // true makes this request async
    Httpreq.onload = function(e) {
        var json_obj = JSON.parse(Httpreq.response);
        var results = json_obj.results;
        yourHandler(results);
    };
    Httpreq.send();
    return Httpreq;
}

var req = Get('https://www.purpleair.com/json?anything', function(results){
    // here you can place some code to do something with results
    // example below: alert the number of the results
    alert(results.length + ' result recieved');
});
```

Comment: Wow, this immediately worked. I can't believe I just had to add *literally* anything to the end of my query string. They must have changed this recently - not sure why they would do this but this is great.

Comment: @KevinSwanberg ...why they did it... well - the response takes about 12secs - it means the server makes a lot of work to produce the response. Might be the case that they tried to limit the data you are asking for with some querystring attribute - just to keep service responsive. Their protection mechanism probably will be improved if your requests will bother them.